# Magnetic Memory to Mars?

Tags: mars, artificial-satellite, cubesat, electronics, trace-gas-orbiter

There [seems to be](http://www.mram-info.com/cobhams-mram-chips-reach-mars-soon) (perhaps [these?](http://www.mram-info.com/aeroflex-launches-16mbit-and-64mbit-mram-chips-based-everspins-technology)) a probe headed to Mars that has incorporated [Magnetic Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistive_random-access_memory) (MRAM) as an integral part of the mission.

Is this a PR gimmick, or is MRAM *actually the best technology* for this mission to Mars? Are there situations where it would be the best choice for cubesats in LEO also?

From [here](http://www.mram-info.com/cobhams-mram-chips-reach-mars-soon):

> ExoMars is a joint-endeavor between the European Space Agency (ESA) and the Russian Federal Space Agency (Roscosmos). ExoMars 2016 is the first mission, that will consist of a Trace Gas Orbiter (TGO) and an entry, descent and landing demonstrator module (EDM) known as Schiaparelli. The main objectives of this mission are to search for evidence of methane and other trace atmospheric gases that could be signatures of active biological or geological processes on Mars.
>
> Cobham's MRAM are used by the Nadir and Occultation for MArs Discovery (NOMAD) instrument on the TGO. NOMAD is a spectrometer suite that will measure the spectrum of sunlight across a wide range of wavelengths, enabling the detection of components of the Martian atmosphere. Cobham says that its MRAM chips were chosen due to the low access time, data retention and footprint, as well as radiation performance. Five MRAMs have been integrated on an interface board on the instrument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExoMars is not the first use of MRAM. In 2007, [SpriteSat](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/s/spritesat) was launched with [MRAM in its magnetometer](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/japanese-satellite-mram-freescale/) subsystem.

In 2012, [JPL tested an MRAM unit](http://nepp.nasa.gov/workshops/etw2012/talks/tuesday/t05_heidecker_mram_technology.pdf) for radiation resistance.

> No latchup observed during any testing.

JPL also launched CubeSat On-board Processing Validation Experiment, “[COVE](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/cubesat/missions/mcubed.php)” with an MRAM on board in 2013.

So no, MRAM's suitability is not a PR gimmick.